# Small positive machine number calculation in Mathematica 11.3

Tags: machine-precision, version-11.3, precision-and-accuracy

In Mathematica version < 11.3, any positive [Machine‐Precision Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html) exceeding the range [`$MinMachineNumber`,`$MaxMachineNumber`] will be automatically converted to [Arbitrary‐Precision Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html). In Mathematica 11.3, however, such conversion for small numbers is [no longer automatic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html).

Programs written in version < 11.3 exploiting such automatic conversion will no longer work in 11.3 out-of-the-box. Although you can always set the precision for a specific number in the calculation process using `SetPrecision` to get an arbitrary-precision number, it will be hard to make sure every single place using such feature is taken care of in older codes.

Is there a way bring the automatic conversion back?